# Affect div when another is targeted

Tags: html, css, lightbox, target

i've got two div's placed inside a li element like this:

```
<li>
    <img src"..." />
    <div-1></div>
    <div-2></div>
<li>
```

Div-1 is a caption overlay of an image, which contains caption and displays on image hover.
Div-2 is a css lightbox with dark background, which popups when clicked on a image.

When lightbox (div-2) is opened (with :target), div-1 remains visible behind div-2 background. Is there an solution that can hide div-1 when div-2 is targeted?

i've tried few variations, but they don't work:

```
li .div-1:target ~ div-2 {display: none}
li > .div-1:target ~ div-2 {display: none}
li > .div-1:target + div-2 {display: none}
```

...and also: [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Couldn't setup a fiddle demo, hope that info above helps.
Any help appriciated :)

Comment: can you change the order of the div's in the markup?

Comment: As far as I know you can't `:target` divs.  It sounds like you're using JavaScript anyway (lightbox display) so you can just use that.

Comment: You need to use the jquerry library

Comment: @avrahamcool yep, still same.

Comment: @Explosion Pills i'm not using javascript, it's css3 lightbox with fixed position of targeted div

Comment: can you please create a fiddle of your setup right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the div's in the markup.

```
<li>
    <img src"..." />
    <div-2></div>
    <div-1></div>
<li>
```

and apply

```
.div-2:target + div-1
{
    display:none;
}
```

now, when `div-2` is targeted, `div-1` disappears.

Comment: Html reorder with `.div-2:target + div-1` worked like a charm, thanks a lot :)